# API Gateway - Body Mapping Template - optional body parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, post, http-post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a POST API Gateway method to which I am sending the following application/json body in order to pass parameters from it to a Lambda that the method is connected to:

```
{ 
    "otherClientId": "12345",
    "message": "Text",
    "seconds": 0,
    "hours": 0
}
```

I am using the following mapping template:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
  "otherClientId": "$inputRoot.otherClientId",
  "message": "$inputRoot.message",
  "amount": $inputRoot.amount,
  "duration": $inputRoot.duration
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that I receive a "Bad String" error when attempting to send the request without amount or duration. For some reason these parameters do not seem to be optional (but I need them to be!).
I am able to miss out other parameters, like message for instance, but not the two number parameters.

Has anybody else experienced this or can somebody point out the obvious that I am probably missing? The AWS documentation is a little sparse on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

Probably, this is happening because without passing those params, your json request looks like:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
  "otherClientId": "$inputRoot.otherClientId",
  "message": "$inputRoot.message",
  "amount": ,
  "duration": 
}
```

The simplest way to fix is to wrap `$inputRoot.amount` and `$inputRoot.duration` with quotes:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
   "authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
   "otherClientId": "$inputRoot.otherClientId",
   "message": "$inputRoot.message",
   "amount": "$inputRoot.amount",
   "duration": "$inputRoot.duration"
}
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate request using if condition for example:

```
#set($hasLimit = $input.params('limit') != "")
#set($hasOffset = $input.params('offset') != "")
#set($hasPeriod = $input.params('period') != "")
#set($hasType = $input.params('type') != "")
{
    "environment": "$input.params('environment')"
    #if($hasLimit),"limit": $input.params('limit')#end
    #if($hasOffset),"offset": $input.params('offset')#end
    #if($hasPeriod),"period": "$input.params('period')"#end
    #if($hasType),"type": "$input.params('type')"#end
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried many combinations around: `#set($hasAuthorizedUser = "$context.authorizer.principalId" != "")
#set($hasMessage = $input.path('$.message') != "")
#set($hasAmount = $input.path('$.amount') != "")
#set($hasDuration = $input.path('$.duration') != "")
{
  #if($hasAuthorizedUser),"authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId"#end
  #if($hasMessage),"message": $input.path('$.message')#end
  #if($hasAmount),"amount": $input.path('$.amount')#end
  #if($hasDuration),"duration": $input.path('$.duration')#end
}` but get a Bad String even with all the params

Comment: Whilst I know that the first solution (using the quotation marks) works, it requires that I convert the strings back to numbers within the Lambda, and that feels wrong to me!

Comment: it seems that you have extra `,` before authorizedUser try: `{ 
    #if($hasAuthorizedUser)"authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId"#end 
    #if($hasMessage),"message": $input.path('$.message')#end 
    #if($hasAmount),"amount": $input.path('$.amount')#end 
    #if($hasDuration),"duration": $input.path('$.duration')#end 
}`

Comment: anyway that the way of doing this, you just need to be careful to make sure you concatenate correct json object

Comment: I will try to play around with concatenation to see if I can get it working. Do you have a link to where this is documented?

Comment: so basically you should test against empty string if you want to know if some field exists, I wonder way `$[{]identifier.identifier[[|alternate value]}]` syntax does not work in API Gateway templates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accidentally referencing the transformed field names via $inputRoot when you want to reference the input field names for 'seconds' and 'hours'. Not sure how you want that mapping to look for amount and duration, but $inputRoot.amount and $inputRoot.duration don't exist in the input you provided.

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "authorizedUser": "$context.authorizer.principalId",
  "otherClientId": "$inputRoot.otherClientId",
  "message": "$inputRoot.message",
  "amount": $inputRoot.seconds,
  "duration": $inputRoot.hours
}
```